# I am getting assertion error on .should('have.value', random_minute) , but it gets passed when I use .should('contains.text', random_minute)

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, assertion

I am using cypress for testing. I am automating a dropdown and validating it after slecting a random number. But I get AssertionError when I get .should('have.value', random_minute). But the same drop down accepts when I used .should('contains.text', random_minute). What should I do , should I pass or fail the test.
Code with should('have.value', random_minute):

```
it('Dropdowns of schedule are working accordingly', () => {
        var checkbox_name = ['dayOfWeekMon', 'dayOfWeekTue', 'dayOfWeekWed',
            'dayOfWeekThu', 'dayOfWeekFri', 'dayOfWeekSat',
            'dayOfWeekSun'];

        var week_wise = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Forth']
        var word = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
            'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
        ];

        var month_word = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
            'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
            'September', 'October', 'November', 'Decemeber'

        ];

        const random_hour = getRandomArbitrary(1, 24)
        const random_dayoftheweek = getRandomDayOftheWeek(word)
        const random_monthoftheyear = getRandomDayOftheWeek(month_word)
        const select_period = ['Minutes', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly']
        cy.wait(10000)
        if (cy.isChecked('#scheduleToggle')) {
            cy
                .get('#scheduleToggle')
                .check({ force: true })


        }

        cy
            .get('#openCronSchedulerModal')
            .should('be.visible')
            .click({ force: true })

        cy
            .get('.cron-period-select')
            .should('have.value', 'Minutes')
        select_period.forEach(($period) => {
            switch ($period) {
                case "Minutes":
                    const random_minute = getRandomArbitrary(1, 60)
                    cy
                        .get('.cron-minutes-select')
                        .should('be.visible')
                        .select(random_minute)
                        // .should('contains.text', random_minute)
                         .should('have.value', random_minute)
                    break;
```

O/P:
[image: AssertionError]

Code with should('contains.text', random_minute):

```
it('Dropdowns of schedule are working accordingly', () => {
            var checkbox_name = ['dayOfWeekMon', 'dayOfWeekTue', 'dayOfWeekWed',
                'dayOfWeekThu', 'dayOfWeekFri', 'dayOfWeekSat',
                'dayOfWeekSun'];
    
            var week_wise = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Forth']
            var word = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
                'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
            ];
    
            var month_word = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                'September', 'October', 'November', 'Decemeber'
    
            ];
    
            const random_hour = getRandomArbitrary(1, 24)
            const random_dayoftheweek = getRandomDayOftheWeek(word)
            const random_monthoftheyear = getRandomDayOftheWeek(month_word)
            const select_period = ['Minutes', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Yearly']
            cy.wait(10000)
            if (cy.isChecked('#scheduleToggle')) {
                cy
                    .get('#scheduleToggle')
                    .check({ force: true })
    
    
            }
    
            cy
                .get('#openCronSchedulerModal')
                .should('be.visible')
                .click({ force: true })
    
            cy
                .get('.cron-period-select')
                .should('have.value', 'Minutes')
            select_period.forEach(($period) => {
                switch ($period) {
                    case "Minutes":
                        const random_minute = getRandomArbitrary(1, 60)
                        cy
                            .get('.cron-minutes-select')
                            .should('be.visible')
                            .select(random_minute)
                            .should('contains.text', random_minute)
                            // .should('have.value', random_minute)
                        break;
```

O/P:
[image: Test Pass]

HTML code:

```
<select class="cron-minutes-select"><option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="41">41</option>
<option value="42">42</option>
<option value="43">43</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="47">47</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="49">49</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="51">51</option>
<option value="52">52</option>
<option value="53">53</option>
<option value="54">54</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="56">56</option>
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
</select>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your failed screenshot shows the expected to be 44, but the value was 45. Did you make sure it selected 44?

Comment: cy.select does that